# r containeRit Dockerfile script file not found

Tags: r, docker, dockerfile

tl;dr: after launching my container the CMD "testScript.r" will not find this file and result in an error.

Setup-folder structure:

- Dockerfile
- testScript.r

My Dockerfile is created with containeRit R package from my session, this is the content of Dockerfile:

```
FROM rocker/r-ver:3.4.2
LABEL maintainer="xyz"
RUN export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive; apt-get -y update \
 && apt-get install -y git-core \
    libcurl4-openssl-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libssh2-1-dev \
    libssl-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    make \
    pandoc \
    pandoc-citeproc \
    zlib1g-dev
RUN ["install2.r", "-r 'https://cloud.r-project.org'", "googleAuthR", "googleCloudStorageR", "Rcpp", "rstudioapi", "magrittr", "hms", "debugme", "rjson", "R6", "rlang", "stringr", "httr", "lambda.r", "futile.logger", "rprojroot", "openssl", "yaml", "assertthat", "digest", "tibble", "crayon", "zip", "readr", "formatR", "futile.options", "curl", "memoise", "mime", "stringi", "pillar", "backports", "desc", "jsonlite", "pkgconfig", "remotes"]
RUN ["installGithub.r", "r-hub/sysreqs@7bdd9f3"]
WORKDIR /payload/
CMD ["R", "--vanilla", "-f", "testScript.r"]
```

I create the image and run docker. This is the result of the following command in terminal:

```
docker run --rm schedulertest
```

Error:

```
Fata error: cannot open file 'testScript.r': No such file or directory
```

Why is that? I'm not to deep into Dockerfile definition, however i could not find any hint on the proper WORKDIR configuration. Since this Dockerfile is created with 'containeRit' package I would have expected it to configure my Dockerfile to run the script properly. How come I run into this error?

Comment: I'm not sure about this format but try running `getwd()` as an expression with the option `-e`.

Comment: Thats an interesting idea, however I'm not sure how to access the output of 'getwd()' after it is executed within my container image. I used to put CMD ["R", "--vanilla", "-e", "getwd()"] into my Dockerfile. But the output is not displayed, it seems to stay within my container.

Comment: Doesn't it write to stdout?. Try `sink('~/Desktop/out.txt');getwd()`

Comment: The Dockerfile needs to have testScript.r within it - so whilst building it you would need to copy in the file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure , but maybe what you need to do is to manually edit the dockerfile enerated by the container::dockerfile().
For example, I don't see any COPY/ADD comand in your dockerfile which indicates that no files, including your r script, have been copied over into your container.

In the dockerfile function there is an option to copy, but better you just add:

COPY ./testRscript.R /folderinthecontainer/testRscript.R.

It will copy over the script and make if findable as an executable.

Answer (score 0):

You should add **copy=** parameter to the containerit::dockerfile function like this:

```
dockerfile_obj <- containerit::dockerfile(from = scriptFile, silent = TRUE, 
     cmd = scriptCmd, copy = list("./"))
```

In this case the created docker file will contains the missing copy command:

```
WORKDIR /payload/
COPY ["./", "./"]
CMD ["R", "--vanilla", "-f", "testScript.r"]
```